# Inscrição em Cursos - Joomla 3.4

Tags: plugin, joomla

Estou precisando de um plugin para joomla ou código para a seguinte situação:

Eu tenho um site que oferece cursos, porém até 6 meses atrás a dona do site, nem site tinha (rss) então ela pediu que fosse feito um modo para que ela tenha os dados dos interessados direto no site.

Ela precisa de um espaço para ela ver quem se inscreveu nos cursos e um formulário para que quem tenha interesse, se inscreva nos cursos... ele não é um E-Commerce, é apenas um formulário com nome, email, cpf e telefone para contato.

Alguém sabe me indicar algum? Se tiverem alguma outra sugestão de como fazer, eu agradeço, pois ainda não sei exatamente como fazer.

OBS.: Se for free melhor ainda :D

Comment: O melhor é você integrar o Joomla com o Moodle, o moodle é um LMS completo de cursos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem muitos plugins que permitem customizar a inscrição usando joomla.

Este [aqui](http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/calendars-a-events/events/event-booking) permite configurar um evento, colocar datas e os campos que deseja coletar dos usuários.

**Edit**

[Esse](http://www.fernandosoares.com.br/index.php?option=com_docman&task=doc_download&gid=28&Itemid=28) outro é gratuito e serve para inscrever-se em cursos exatamente como proposto. O nome é *Attend Events* e está em português.

Comment: Esse é pago, conhece algum free? Como eu posso mostrar pra cliente quem se inscreveu nos cursos usando esse que você me passou?

Comment: Vai abrir uma seção na parte admin que conterá a lista de inscritos

Comment: @Isabela, vou ver se acho um free.

Comment: Veja na resposta editada.

Comment: Erro 404.. acho que o teu link foi removido

Comment: @Isabela, corrigi o link, ele estava apenas colado 2 vezes :D